# Primefaces Tree node is draggable to children

Tags: jsf, primefaces, tree

I have a PrimeFaces (6.2.5) tree, where I have enabled draggable and droppable. I have a few issues with this, and have implemented the drag and drop manually with jquery in stead, while I figure this out;

```
   <div class="plantree" id="realplantree">
   <p:tree id="plantree" value="#{curriculumngTreeFacade.root}" var="node" dynamic="false" selectionMode="single" selection="#{curriculumngTreeFacade.selectedNode}" draggable="true" droppable="true">
        <p:ajax event="select" listener="#{curriculumngTreeFacade.onNodeSelect}"  update="administration-form:curriculummain" oncomplete="initDNDPlan();"/>
        <p:ajax event="expand" listener="#{curriculumngTreeFacade.onNodeExpand}" />
        <p:ajax event="collapse" listener="#{curriculumngTreeFacade.onNodeCollapse}" />
        <p:ajax event="dragdrop" listener="#{curriculumngTreeFacade.onDragDrop}"/>
        <p:treeNode expandedIcon="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open" collapsedIcon="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-collapsed">
          <h:outputText value="#{node}"/>
        </p:treeNode>
    </p:tree>
</div>
```

My issues are:

- I have not added an "update='plantree'" variable to the p:ajax event
  for dragdrop. Even still, if I try and drag a parent category to  a
  sub category, it breaks my tree, because the UI tries to update. I
  actually run a check for parent / child connection in the backend
  code, and I dont update the tree if that's the case, but in this
  case, my method in the backing bean is not even called before the
  tree explodes. It does the very same on the [PrimeFaces Showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/tree/dragdrop.xhtml)

Backing code:

```
public void onDragDrop(TreeDragDropEvent event) throws Exception {
TreeNode dragNode = event.getDragNode();
TreeNode dropNode = event.getDropNode();

int dropIndex = event.getDropIndex();
if (dragNode.getData() instanceof CurriculumCategoryMetaModel && dropNode.getData() instanceof CurriculumCategoryMetaModel) {

  CurriculumCategoryMetaModel drop = (CurriculumCategoryMetaModel) dropNode.getData();
  CurriculumCategoryMetaModel drag = (CurriculumCategoryMetaModel) dragNode.getData();

  if (drop.getType() == drag.getType() && drag.getClassid() > 0) {
    drag.setParent(drop);
    CurriculumBuilderProvider provider = CurriculumBuilderProvider.getProvider(drop.getType());
    provider.saveCategory(drag, UserSessionFacade.getUserLocale());
    this.initialize();
    expandCategory(root, drop.getClassid(), drop.getType());
  } else {
    this.initialize();
  }

}

FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Dragged " + dragNode.getData(), "Dropped on " + dropNode.getData() + " at " + dropIndex);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
List<String> updates = new ArrayList<>();
updates.add("administration-form:curriculummenu");
updates.add("administration-form:growl");
PrimeFaces.current().ajax().update(updates);
```

}

```
private boolean dragIsParentOfDrop(CurriculumCategoryMetaModel drop, CurriculumCategoryMetaModel drag) {
CurriculumCategoryMetaModel parent = drop.getParent();
while (parent != null) {
  if (parent.getClassid() == drag.getClassid()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    parent = parent.getParent();
  }
}
return false;
```

}

- Is there a way to add accepted nodes that you can drop into. I have 2
  root nodes, for different categories, and it is not allowed to drag
  and drop between them. In fact, I dont even want the root nodes to be
  draggable. On the picture, the "Learning paths" and "Ad hoc" are not supposed to be draggable, since they're only containers for the categories underneath. [image]

Comment: If you want to enable drag/drop among the siblings only, you can add attribute `dropRestrict="sibling"`.

Comment: Also since you have mentioned that you use jquery, could you edit the post and add the functions related to it. (For eg, what is `initDNDPlan()` in `oncomplete`)

Comment: Oh - I just forgot to edit that out. I have altered my production code to use a jQuery fraggable function in stead. The oncomplete should not be there.